# In $Z_p\times Z_p$, if the product of two group subsets of order $p$ and contain the identiy is the whole group, then one of them is a subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, p-groups

This should be elementary, and I figured it should be true, but I can't find a good argument on it:

Let 
$$G=\mathbb Z_p\times \mathbb Z_p,$$ 
where $p$ is a prime number. 
Let $S,H$ be subsets of $G$ with order
$$|S|=|H|=p,$$
and
$$e\in H,S$$
i.e., both contains the identity element. Let us write the elements in $H$ as 
$$H=\{h_1,h_2,h_3,\ldots, h_p\},$$
now, if
$$\{h_1S,h_2S,h_3S,\ldots, h_pS\},$$
is a partition of $G$, i.e.,
$$G=HS,$$
does it follow that either $H$ or $S$ must be a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: $G=\mathbb{Z}$, $S= \mathbb{N}$ and $H = -\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Nex, thanks, but I mentioned explicitly that $G$ is $Z_p\times Z_p$

Comment: What went wrong is that your title is stated generally, the answer is obviously "no", as shown by @Nex.

Comment: In general if $G$ has at least four elements, then $H = S = G\setminus \{e\}$ will work. For $g \in G$ either $g= e$ (in which case $g$ is the product of some element and its inverse) or else choose any $g' \neq e,g,g^{-1}$ and then $g = g' ((g')^{-1}g)$ (with $g'$ and $(g')^{-1} g$ in $H=S$).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a question I asked in 2016, a few years ago I got to know the answer and it is not so elementary as it appears to be, so let me post it here and close this question.

The answer is Yes, and it follows from a classical result of Hajos and Redei, which says that if $G$ is a finite Abelian group and $G=A_1\times\ldots\times A_d$ where $A_1,\ldots, A_d$ are normalized (i.e., contains the identity) subset of $G$, and the product is direct (i.e., each $g\in G$ can be uniquely written as $g=a_1+\ldots+a_d$ with $a_i\in A_i$), then at least one of $A_1,\ldots, A_d$ is a subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

For $p=3$ a counterexample (using additive notation) is

$S=\{(0,1),(0,2),(1,1)\}$, $H=\{(1,0),(0,2),(2,1)\}$.

Comment: Your $H$ is a coset of a subgroup...

Comment: But it's not a subgroup. You asked "does it follow  that $H$ or $S$ must be a asubgroup of $G$?", and the answer is no.

Comment: Now you have the changed the question. You should not change a question after it has been correctly answered.